# C# form input logging

Tags: c#, sql

I have a procedure that checks user input. I want it to be added to my logs when the user logs in. But when I try this way it adds though the login fails.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_KullaniciGiris]
@username varchar(10),
@pw nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT*FROM Kullanicilar WHERE username=@username AND
pw=@pw and IsActive=1

END

INSERT INTO LogIslem(Kullanici,LogText,Sayfa,Islem)
VALUES(
@username,
+'username:'+@username+
'pw:'+@pw,
'FormLogin',
'Login'
)
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged C#?

Comment: The ENd  needs to come aftet ther insert

Comment: Don't forget to add a tag for dbms used. (Product specific question/answer.)